# C# pattern creation for receiving an integer from a string

Tags: c#, pattern-matching

i have some string like the ones below:

```
hu212 text = 1
reference = 1
racial construction = 1
2007 = 1
20th century history = 2
```

and i want to take only the integer AFTER the '='.. how can i do that?
i am trying this:

```
 Regex exp = new Regex(@"[a-zA-Z]*[0-9]*[=][0-9]+",RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
            try
            {
                MatchCollection MatchList = exp.Matches(line);
                Match FirstMatch = MatchList[0];
                Console.WriteLine(FirstMatch.Value);
            }catch(ArgumentOutOfRangeException ex)
            {
                System.Console.WriteLine("ERROR");
            }
```

but it is not working...
i tryed some others but i get results like "20th" or "hu212"...
What exaclty Matches does? gives me the rest of the string that doesn match with the reg?

Comment: You can use the `IndexOf` and `Substring` methods of `String`.

Comment: why can't you use string.split function? just a thought..

Answer (score 5):

Instead of Regex you could also do:

```
int match = int.Parse(line.SubString(line.IndexOf('=')).Trim());
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to allow whitespace (`\s`) between the `=` and the digits:

```
Regex pattern = new Regex(@"=\s*([0-9]+)$");
```

Here's a more complete example:

```
Regex pattern = new Regex(@"=\s*([0-9]+)$");
Match match = pattern.Match(input);
if (match.Success) 
{
    int value = int.Parse(match.Groups[1].Value);
    // Use the value
}
```

See it working online: [ideone](http://ideone.com/ZJvFD)

Comment: +1 for not berating the guy for using a very simple Regex. *And* for answering his question

Comment: something like that.. but i dont want the '='

Comment: the OP doesn't stipulate that it must be Regex.

Comment: @Michael: Not this post, I was impressed at the gentleness of this set of responses.  I've noticed an increasing trend of varying degrees of rudeness when people try to use Regex'es for something on S.O.  I've been avoiding posts with Regex in title b/c it irritates me.

Comment: SpDaglas - as long as you the "Groups" part of the match (as he had in the code above) you won't get anything that wasn't captured in groups, which his equal and space weren't. Check out his online example - I think you'll find it to be exactly what you wanted.

Answer (score 1):

what about

```
string str = "hu212 text = 1"
string strSplit = str.split("=")[1].trim();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String StringToParse = "hu212 text = 1";
String[] splitString = String.Split(StringToParse);

Int32 outNum;
Int32.TryParse ( splitString[splitString.Length-1], out outNum );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 Regex pattern = new Regex(@"=\s?(\d)");
```

This allow to have with or without space. The number is in group 1.

```
hu212 text =1
reference = 1
```